# How to use PropertyChanged instead of TextBox TextChanged event in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to use `PropertyChanged` instead of `TextChanged` on TextBox in WPF ? How to know if `PropertyChanged` triggered or not ?

I have TextBox like this:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="kodpTxt" Text="{Binding Selected.KodP,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="75" Margin="84,55,0,0" />
```

I would prefer to avoid `TextChanged` event, because I change `kodpTxt` binding from database and it's length is not always same, so I can't check if `kodpTxt.Text.Length >= 5` etc.

I was looking for alternative and realized that maybe I can do something with `PropertyChanged` but I don't know how to find out when `PropertyChanged` happened.

```
private string _kodp;

public string KodP
{
    get { return _kodp; }
    set
    {
        _kodp = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("KodP");
    }
}
public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

To visualise my problem I will describe it a little:

I have `ViewModel` and `UserControl` with `kodpTxt` TextBox. In `UserControl` I set up `Selected.XYZ` propierties. Onfurtunetly I can't manipulate `UserControl` controls from `ViewModel`. That's why I'm looking for something like:

```
public void kodpTxt_PropertyChanged()
{
    //Do Something (get data from SqlServer and pass them to some UserControl controls
}
```

[image: Description]

Can you explain that ?

Comment: You can certainly find out in the ViewModel, more concise you could raise an event in the setter of your `Selected.KodP` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Mode=TwoWay`

```
<TextBox x:Name="kodpTxt" Text="{Binding Selected.KodP, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="75" Margin="84,55,0,0" />
```

And you will get invoked `setter` for `Selected.KodP` property.
That's how you can get this event.

Comment: Gave +1, but I cannot do I want to do in setter.

Comment: @fanarek why can you not use the `TextChanged` event? As far as I am concerned, using the binding mode `TwoWay`, you can use the `TextChanged` event exactly like you want to use the (nonexisting) `PropertyChanged` event.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow Right, found it out. Thanks

Comment: Okay, nice to hear that you could solve it @fanarek.

Answer (score 1):

As [Alexy has already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49256295/7571171) use `Mode.TwoWay` in the binding so that you can perform your checks in the property setter like this:

```
public string KodP
{
    get { return ... }
    set
    {
        if(value.Length >= 5)
        {
            ...
        }

        // Set the value to your field / database etc.
    }
}
```

Using this method, there is no need for any event to be called, since you can do the check / invoke methods etc. in the property setter directly.